# Amazon Polly, how to read foreign languages with non ascii

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

So I am creating an app that lets you convert text to a desired language, and submit it to aws polly. The issue is that when you start getting weird characters in other languages, such as the é sign, or Japanese character, polly.synthesize_speech doesn't like them, and fails the call. How do you submit languages to be read that use non ascii characters?

Comment: The documentation says, [Some alphabets might not be available with all the voices.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html) Is that the problem?

Comment: No, it's not not the alphabet. The synthesize speech function won't even take other languages that use non ascii characters as an option.